# Deprecated command StrPas

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-xe6

When i try to compile my code I get the below error. Could anyone suggest what am I doing wrong here?

```
W1000 Symbol 'StrPas' is deprecated: 'Moved to the AnsiStrings unit'
```

The code fragment that i'm trying to compile is:

```
{$IFDEF NEWVER} // Codegear delphi 2009    d12.0
      StrCopy(pSerialNumber, @Buf[pDevDesc.SerialNumberOffset + 1]);
{$ELSE}
      StrPCopy(pSerialNumber,
        FlipAndCodeBytes(StrPas(@Buf[pDevDesc.SerialNumberOffset + 1])));
{$ENDIF}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to decipher the previous programmer's intent leads to another possibility....

It seems there was a fix applied for Delphi 2009 due to the changes in the **string** type. I'm sure you don't want to reinvent all the fixes that another programmer has already done.

---

Looking at the code, Delphi 2009 is intended to compile the following line (which doesn't use `StrPas`):

```
  StrCopy(pSerialNumber, @Buf[pDevDesc.SerialNumberOffset + 1]);
```

And older versions of Delphi are intended to compile the following line (which **does** use `StrPas`):

```
  StrPCopy(pSerialNumber,
    FlipAndCodeBytes(StrPas(@Buf[pDevDesc.SerialNumberOffset + 1])));
```

Delphi XE-6 would not in this case be classified as an "older version", so the error is that you're compiling the wrong branch of the conditional code.

---

The conditional code will compile the first statement if `NEWVER` is defined. So if you ensure that `NEWVER` is defined you should be compiling the correct line. You might need to modify an appropriate include file, or set the conditonal as an option in the project file. (It depends on how your environment is set up.)

However the name of that conditional symbol `NEWVER` is somewhat inappropriate. Clearly 2009 is no longer the "new version" - in fact even XE6 is now an "older version".

So you may want to rewrite your conditional as follows:

```
{$IF CompilerVersion >= 20.0} //>= Delphi 2009
    StrCopy(pSerialNumber, @Buf[pDevDesc.SerialNumberOffset + 1]);
{$ELSE}
    StrPCopy(pSerialNumber,
        FlipAndCodeBytes(StrPas(@Buf[pDevDesc.SerialNumberOffset + 1])));
{$IFEND}
```

See the following links for more information on conditional defines:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Compiler_Versions

If you need to support much older versions of Delphi (older than Delphi 6 if I'm not mistaken), you may need to write the above code as:

```
{$IFDEF CONDITIONALEXPRESSIONS}
    {$IF CompilerVersion >= 20.0} //>= Delphi 2009
        StrCopy(pSerialNumber, @Buf[pDevDesc.SerialNumberOffset + 1]);
    {$ELSE} //< Delphi 2009
        StrPCopy(pSerialNumber,
            FlipAndCodeBytes(StrPas(@Buf[pDevDesc.SerialNumberOffset + 1])));
    {$IFEND}
{$ELSE} //< Delphi 6
    StrPCopy(pSerialNumber,
        FlipAndCodeBytes(StrPas(@Buf[pDevDesc.SerialNumberOffset + 1])));
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: This seems very plausible, I did not spot that, +1

Comment: @jim I'd actually go further than Craig did here. Ask yourself why you are maintaining code that you never compile? You aren't going back to ANSI Delphi are you? So strip out all of the ANSI/Unicode conditional code and write it like this: `StrCopy(pSerialNumber, @Buf[pDevDesc.SerialNumberOffset + 1]);` That's all. Do this throughout your code base.

Answer (score 7):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrPas) has the answer. It says:

> This function is provided for backwards compatibility only. To convert a null-terminated string to an AnsiString or native Delphi language string, use a typecast or an assignment.

So instead of `StrPas(...)` you should cast to either `AnsiString` or `UnicodeString` depending on whether or not the buffer is 8 bit or 16 bit.

Comment: thanks this helps. But i'm hit with similar errors in 
StrCopy(ds.SerialNumber, pSerialNumber); 

here SerialNumber is an array. Any clue?

Comment: This is a different question. The solution is to follow the advice in the deprecation warning. Include `System.AnsiStrings` after `System.SysUtils` in your uses clause so that you use `System.AnsiStrings.StrCopy` rather than `System.SysUtils.StrCopy`. Or even better, be explicit and use a fully qualified name.

Comment: thanks. It helped me to correct the error. Appreciate your help.